# Bash script ends without doing echo

Tags: bash, shell, jmeter

I am running a script from command line that runs a bunch of Jmeter tests if 4 variables are set.

The script works but I have added parts so the script will end if the server is unknown.

```
if [ echo "$2" != | grep -iq "^hibagon" ] || [ echo "$2" != | grep -iq "^kameosa" ] ;then
echo "Unkown server stopping tests" 
  else
echo "Continueing to tests"
```

when this section of the script runs it will end the script if hibagon or kameosa is not found (not case sensitive).

I want the command line to echo Unknown server stopping tests then end but at the moment it just ends with no echo

Comment: you are missing `fi` at the end

Comment: Those conditions doesn't make any sense. Maybe you mean e.g. `[ $(echo "$2" | grep -iq "^hibagon") ]`?

Comment: @Joachim rather than testing a command substitution, you should just test the commands directly as [both](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29966043/2088135) [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29966073/2088135) have shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a strange syntax. Try this:

```
if echo "$2" | grep -iq "^hibagon\|^kameosa";
then 
    echo "Continuing to tests"
else
    echo "Unkown server, stopping tests" 
fi
```

Or if you're using bash:

```
if [[ "$2" =~ ^hibagon ]] || [[ "$2" =~ ^kameosa ]]
then
    echo "Continuing to tests"
else
    echo "Unkown server, stopping tests" 
fi
```

Comment: the regex in either case could be `^(hibagon|kameosa)`, using `grep -E` to get extended regex support there too. For compatibility reasons it's recommended to declare a variable: `re='^(hibagon|kameosa)'; if [[ $2 =~ $re ]]; then ...` - the variables in the test are intentionally left unquoted.

Comment: BRE is perfectly fine here, and yes, I tested both solutions before posting (GNU Bash v4.2.53)

Comment: I wasn't implying your code was wrong - I was merely making some suggestions. It's up to you whether you prefer escaping pipes/groups or adding a switch, in this case it doesn't make much difference. Your bash version works perfectly fine but [it is recommended](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Patterns#Regular_Expressions-1) to use a variable for regular expressions in bash. Either way, a single test is better than two tests in my opinion.

Comment: Ok, I agree then. Thanks for the link, I'll try to refresh my knowledge some time.

Comment: This has helped fix my problem for this section of my script thanks

Answer (score 1):

First the test `[ echo "$2" != | grep -iq "^hibagon" ]` is wrong, then you can use only one (extended)grep with the negation flag `-v` putting together the two words in one regex `^(hibagon|kameosa)`. Also the `fi` was missing. but I suppose it's only a typo here.

```
if echo "$2" | egrep -ivq "^(hibagon|kameosa)"; then
    echo "Unknown server stopping tests" 

else
    echo "Continuing to tests"

fi
```

If you like it, even:

```
if egrep -ivq "^(hibagon|kameosa)" <<< "$2"; then
```