# BASH script ends for unknown reason during IF

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, jmeter

I have a bash script that runs a bunch of Jmeter scripts.
I have just modified the script so it will only run if the environment variable is set correctly (one of 2 in this case).

If the first environment is used the script ends.
If the second environment choice is used the script runs and completes correctly.

FULL SCRIPT:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$#" -ne 4 ]; then
    echo "Parameters required: version environment plc_username plc_password"
else
    cd $HOME/workspace/OptimumStart/resources/jmeterrun/

    if [[ "$2" =~ ^hibagon ]]; then
        echo 'doing hibagon'
        echo 'using version '$1 
        source ./hibagon_env.sh $1 
        echo 'done hibagon env'
    elif [[ "$2" =~ ^kameosa ]]; then
        echo 'doing kameosa'
        echo 'using version '$1 
        source ./kameosa_env.sh $1 
        echo 'done kameosa env'
        if [[ "$2" =~ ^hibagon ]] || [[ "$2" =~ ^kameosa ]]; then
            echo "Continuing to tests"
            source ./user_env.sh $3 $4
            echo 'done user env'
            export jmtestFeature=DEV15298
            env | grep jm
            $HOME/apache-jmeter-2.11/bin/jmeter -n -t $HOME/workspace/OptimumStart/resources/jmeterscripts/DEV15298_Feedback/QA3 1985_AllowCoolingZwaveFeedback.jmx
            echo 'done Allow Cooling Tests'
            $HOME/apache-jmeter-2.11/bin/jmeter -n -t $HOME/workspace/OptimumStart/resources/jmeterscripts/DEV15298_Feedback/QA3 1986_WarmingZwaveFeedback.jmx
            echo 'done Warming Tests'
            $HOME/apache-jmeter-2.11/bin/jmeter -n -t $HOME/workspace/OptimumStart/resources/jmeterscripts/DEV15298_Feedback/QA3 1987_MaintainingZwaveFeedback.jmx
            echo 'done Maintaining Tests'
            $HOME/apache-jmeter-2.11/bin/jmeter -n -t $HOME/workspace/OptimumStart/resources/jmeterscripts/DEV15298_Feedback/QA31993_PreHeatingZwaveFeedback.jmx
            echo 'done Pre Heating Tests'
            $HOME/apache-jmeter-2.11/bin/jmeter -n -t $HOME/workspace/OptimumStart/resources/jmeterscripts/DEV15298_Feedback/QA-32651_PreZwaveOccChange.jmx
            echo 'Done Occupancy change test'
            $HOME/apache-jmeter-2.11/bin/jmeter -n -t $HOME/workspace/OptimumStart/resources/jmeterscripts/Createtree.jmx
            echo 'Created tree of results'  
        else
            echo "Unkown server, stopping tests"
        fi
    fi
fi
```

The section that seems to be causing me problem is

```
if [[ "$2" =~ ^hibagon ]]; then
  echo 'doing hibagon'
  echo 'using version '$1 
  source ./hibagon_env.sh $1 
  echo 'done hibagon env'
elif [[ "$2" =~ ^kameosa ]]; then
  echo 'doing kameosa'
  echo 'using version '$1 
  source ./kameosa_env.sh $1 
  echo 'done kameosa env'
```

The following happens if run from command line using 3 different environments.

```
./jmeterrun2.sh testversion kameosa  shaun shaun
doing kameosa
using version testversion
done kameosa env
Continuing to tests
done user env
jmtestFeature=DEV15298
OLDPWD=/home/shaunb/workspace/OptimumStart/resources/jmeterrun
jmuser=shaun
jmpass=shaun
jmPort=443
PWD=/home/shaunb/workspace/OptimumStart/resources/jmeterrun
jmtestVersion=testversion
jmHost=kameosa.passivonline.com
```

And continues to run scripts.

```
./jmeterrun2.sh testversion hibagon  shaun shaun
doing hibagon
using version testversion
done hibagon env
```

This just stops there and does nothing

```
./jmeterrun2.sh testversion noserver  shaun shaun
```

This does nothing

If you need more information please tell me.

Comment: You're missing a `fi` in the block you highlighted.

Comment: @Mat I moved a fi from the bottom of the script to after the echo 'done kameosa env'  and that fixed my problem thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bash script ends without doing echo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29965859/bash-script-ends-without-doing-echo)

Answer (score 0):

I've factored your script into a function library, which i've called jmFunctionLib.   you "source"  or "dot (.)" the library. e.g.:

```
ittoolbox.$ . ./jmFunctionLib
ONLY executable statement
USAGE: myJmrun version environment plc_username plc_password
```

I'd hope you'd work with this.  The objective of this style is to develop a practice that helps you avoid the "what's wrong with this script" type of question.  How?

1. by giving you testable intermediate blocks of code (functions)
2. by collapsing long stretches of code which make nesting difficult to   follow,
3. by collecting repeatedly use commands into a more semantic   form,
   e.g. it's likely that the "myJmaster" function becomes the   "main".
4. maintenance becomes much easier.

enjoy!  the function library:

```
function comment
{ 
    echo $* 1>&2
}
function quietly
{ 
    "$@" 2> /dev/null
}
function myJminit
{
    comment USAGE: myJmrun version environment plc_username plc_password
    quietly comment 1. put all announcements on stderr as comments;
    quietly comment 2. collapse into functions;
    quietly comment 3. recognize parallel logic
}
function myJmeter
{ 
    $HOME/apache-jmeter-2.11/bin/jmeter -n -t \
    $HOME/workspace/OptimumStart/resources/jmeterscripts/"$1";
    comment done $(echo "$1"|sed 's/.*_//; s/.jmx$//') Tests
}
function myJmfeed
{ 
    myJmeter DEV15298_Feedback/"$1"
}
function myJmRun
{ 
    [[ $# -lt 4 ]] && { 
        myJminit
        return
    };
    cd $HOME/workspace/OptimumStart/resources/jmeterrun/;
    case $2 in 
        *hibagon* | *kameosa*)
            myJmaster "$@"
        ;;
        *)
            comment Unkown server, stopping tests
        ;;
    esac
}
function myJmaster
{ 
    comment "doing $2";
    comment "using version $1";
    source ${2}_env.sh;
    comment done $2 env;
    comment contintuing to tests;
    source ./user_env.sh $3 $4;
    comment done user env;
    export jmtestFeature=DEV15298;
    comment $(env | grep jm );
    myJmfeed "QA3 1985_AllowCoolingZwaveFeedback.jmx";
    myJmfeed "QA3 1986_WarmingZwaveFeedback.jmx";
    myJmfeed "QA3 1987_MaintainingZwaveFeedback.jmx";
    myJmfeed "QA31993_PreHeatingZwaveFeedback.jmx";
    myJmfeed "QA-32651_PreZwaveOccChange.jmx";
    myJmeter Createtree.jmx
}
comment ONLY executable statement; myJminit
```